# How can I automatically change one value after x hours?

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a ban/unban feature for a school project. I have one User table with one is_banned column. Whenever I do one Update query to change the status from unbanned to banned I want to pass a value containing for how long the user is banned. Let's say 24 hours. The thing is I want to automatically unban him after that time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, banning is probably not a common occurrence, so you *could* use events.  When someone is banned, create an event to unban the person.

I still don't like that idea.  The database might happen to be down when the unban job is supposed to run.  The user might be banned again, extending the ban period.

I think a better way is to have a column in the table (say `users`) with the most recent ban time.  Then create a view to get the unbanned users:

```
create view v_users as
    select u.*
    from users u
    where u.bantime is null or u.bantime < now() - interval 24 hour;
```

The key is to use this view whenever your code wants unbanned users.

Or, if you just want a flag:

```
create view v_users as
    select u.*, (u.bantime > now() - interval 24 hour) as isBanned
    from users u;
```

Comment: Hey, this is still quite hard for me, let me get this straight, so whenever I run the UPDATE query to change is_banned = 0 to is_banned = 1, I also have to update a column named bantime? And in bantime I could pass let's say 48 for 48 hours?

Comment: @VeraPerrone . . . Actually, just forget `is_banned` and use `bantime`.  Use the view to calculate `is_banned`.

Comment: Above can be even shortened if you save `banned_until`. In this case `interval 24 hour` can be omitted.